# Slow cheetah not transforming file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, slowcheetah

I have slow cheetah installed in my solution in Asp.Net application.

I have log4net.config file in library project which is included in web application and I have added transformations for it. When I preview transformation it shows correct transformed file, and when I build solution and go to library folder/bin/environemnt_name I can see transformed file but in web application in bin folder it is still old not transformed log4net.config file.

Why doesnt the transformed file get copied to web application?

Comment: Transforming only happens on Publish.  Do you have the config file set to Content and not copy to output?  Should transform when you publish the site to the root.

Comment: It doesnt happen on publish too, but I see there is already that issue listed on slow cheetah github.